# Flash Message in YII Framework

Tags: yii

After I send the request, I will announce the result to the user via SET FLASH. What is the way to show a message when the user sends a request?

For example when sending a message form : Display -> form is being send and then a flash message is displayed

Comment: Please, add your code

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Check the wiki on the Yii framework website:
http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/21/how-to-work-with-flash-messages/

In your controller you can put:

```
Yii::app()->user->setFlash('success', "Form posted!");
```

In your view you can echo the flash message by:

```
<?php echo Yii::app()->user->getFlash('success'); ?>
```

Optionally you can check if a flash message exists by using the hasFlash method, so the code in your view would look like this:

```
<?php if(Yii::app()->user->hasFlash('success')):?>

      <?php echo Yii::app()->user->getFlash('success'); ?>

<?php endif; ?>
```

Answer (score 2):

Add `setFlash` in your controller. Something like this:

```
if($comment->save())
{
    Yii::app()->user->setFlash('commentSubmitted','Thank you for your comment.');
    $this->refresh();
}
```

And in your views, display flash message something like this:

```
<?php if(Yii::app()->user->hasFlash('commentSubmitted')): ?>
    <div class="flash-success">
        <?php echo Yii::app()->user->getFlash('commentSubmitted'); ?>
    </div>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

In your controller you can put:

```
if(conditions)
   Yii::app()->user->setFlash('success', "Success text");
else
   Yii::app()->user->setFlash('error', "Error text");
```

In your view you can echo the flash message by:

```
<?php
if(Yii::app()->user->hasFlash('success'))
    Yii::app()->user->setFlash('success', '<strong>Well done!</strong> '.Yii::app()->user->getFlash('success').'.');
else
    Yii::app()->user->setFlash('error', '<strong>Error!</strong> '.Yii::app()->user->getFlash('error').'.');


$this->widget('bootstrap.widgets.TbAlert', array(
    'block'=>true, // display a larger alert block?
    'fade'=>true, // use transitions?
    'closeText'=>'&times;', // close link text - if set to false, no close link is displayed
    'alerts'=>array( // configurations per alert type
        'success'=>array('block'=>true, 'fade'=>true, 'closeText'=>'&times;'), // success, info, warning, error or danger
    ),
)); ?>
```