# save message is not displayed in yii form

Tags: php, html, yii

I have 2 forms, the save message is displayed for 1st, but don't display on another.

1st view give confirmation message but the 2nd don't, the data is saved in tables.

[gist for codes](https://gist.github.com/nadeem14375/ccce3a20b3e4e24a1113cef50c1c103e)

in the above gist, you can see the controller and views for both.

Comment: Please post your controller code.

Comment: add the code to gist

Comment: you can refer this link for you problem : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18314813/flash-message-in-yii-framework

Comment: added the echo Yii::app()->user->getFlash('success'); before $this->endWidget(); please check the gist, but no message

Answer (score 1):

You can used this code for you solution. Check set Message code in below.

**view.php**

```
    <div class="ibox">
        <div class="ibox-heading">
            <div class="ibox-title">
                <h3><?PHP echo(($model->isNewRecord) ? 'Create Fee Structure' : 'Update Fee Structure'); ?></h3>
            </div>
        </div>
        <!-- /.box-header -->
        <!-- Set Message start -->
        <?php if(Yii::app()->user->hasFlash('confirm')):?>
              <div class="info">
                  <?php echo Yii::app()->user->getFlash('confirm'); ?>
              </div>
        <?php endif; ?>
        <!-- Message end -->    

        <!-- form start -->
        <?php
        $form = $this->beginWidget('CActiveForm', array(
            'id' => 'fee_structure_form',
            'enableAjaxValidation' => true,
            'htmlOptions' => array(
                'enctype' => 'multipart/form-data',
                'role' => 'form'
            ),
            'clientOptions' => array(
                'validateOnSubmit' => true,
                'validateOnChange' => true,
                'validateOnType' => false,
            ),
        ));    ?>
        <div class="ibox-content">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-6 col-xs-12">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <?PHP
                        echo $form->label($model, 'class_id');
                        echo $form->dropDownList($model, 'class_id', $studentClasses,array('placeholder' => 'Class', 'class' => 'form-control'));
                        echo $form->error($model,'class_id');
                        ?>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <?PHP
                        echo $form->label($model, 'fee_type');
                        echo $form->dropDownList($model, 'fee_type', $feeTypes, array('placeholder' => 'Fee Type', 'class' => 'form-control'));
                        echo $form->error($model,'fee_type');
                        ?>
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group">
                        <?PHP
                        echo $form->label($model, 'amount');
                        echo $form->textField($model, 'amount', array('placeholder' => 'Amount', 'class' => 'form-control'));
                        echo $form->error($model,'amount');
                        ?>
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group">
                        <?PHP
                        echo $form->label($model, 'remarks');
                        echo $form->textField($model, 'remarks', array('placeholder' => 'Remarks', 'class' => 'form-control'));
                        echo $form->error($model,'remarks');
                        ?>
                    </div>   
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="ibox-footer col-md-12 col-xs-12" style="margin-bottom: 60px;">
            <button class="btn col-md-3 col-xs-12 btn-primary pull-left" type="submit">
                <?PHP echo Definations::SAVEFORM; ?>
            </button>
        </div>
        <?PHP
        $this->endWidget();
        ?>
    </div>
```

Comment: unable to produce the message, what can be the problem?

Comment: found getFlash('confirm'); in /themes/default/views/layouts/main.php please have a look in this gist https://gist.github.com/nadeem14375/06e2d7a5177888bc11a977c1bb9a8d51

Comment: I couldn't find any differnece in both forms, "StuClass" and "FeeStructure". for first I can see the message but no message for 2nd.

Comment: Just changed the $message text confirmed that the message is  getting from main.php, but unable to understand why this is not showing on "FeeStructure" form.